# jQuery check for uploaded file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-validate

I'm using Paperclip gem. Everything is working fine, but the problem is that, if a user uploads a video file in the wrong format, the error message is not displayed until after the upload has taken place. Can I check this with jQuery validate plugin? I would like to validate video files of correct type.

I have added the below in my js file. This works fine for me but 
some extensions are not allowed. Example **small.webm** is a valid video file. Unable to upload this. Because this  extension is not in my validation. I want to have validations that support all video files or Is there any other way to do it simply?

```
'file[video]' : { required: true,
                      accept: 'ogg|ogv|avi|mpe?g|mov|wmv|flv|mp4'
                    },
```

Comment: Great question! There seem to be a lot of ways to around this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110032/jquery-file-upload-content-type-extension-validation & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553307/jquery-to-verify-file-type-and-file-size-before-submitting

Comment: @RichPeck- Thanks. But I don't want to specify any video content type. The video field should allow all video files whatever the video format is(like mpeg,mp4.flv,avi etc......). I want to implement this with jQuery validate plugin.

Comment: Wrong rule.  Replace `accept` with `extension`.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up the `accept` method with the `extension` method.

```
'file[video]': {
    required: true,
    extension: 'ogg|ogv|avi|mpe?g|mov|wmv|flv|mp4'
},
```

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/

Don't forget to include the `additional-methods.js` file!

Comment: @Joe, read the docs.  `accept` is for mime types and `extension` is for file extensions.  If you think those two things work the same, good luck.